# Postfix Configuration

Tags: postfix

I need to configure a Postfix mail server for the following scenario,

Assuming there are 200 users with user ids 20001 to 20200.

1. Incoming emails of the Users having user ids from 20001 to 20100 should only be accepted when the sender domain is "aol.com", "rediff.com". Else the emails should be rejected.
2. Incoming emails of the Users having user ids from 20101 to 20200 should only be accepted if their age is between 40 and 50 and the total number of emails in their maildir doesn't exceed 2000.

   - The birthday of the users will be stored in the MySQL db but not the age.

Please do suggest me with the suitable steps. I'm using Postfix MTA and MySQL db.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For both purposes the cleanest solution would be to create a policy service as described in [SMTPD_POLICY_README](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have gone through the link which you have provided. I'm a newbie to postfix MTA configuration. 

Can you please provide me with any other referral links for ease of understanding ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'd suggest you to buy the book "Book of postfix".
It's a must for anyone has to configure postfix

Comment: @Pier

Sure :) I'll get one soon.